# A Nuget package copies the static files from its reference project when installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, project-reference, packagereference

I have a project called "A" project, and it contain some static files (like dll or others).

And it's csproj is as follow

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ContentWithTargetPath Include="files\MyDll.dll">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        <TargetPath>MyDll.dll</TargetPath>
    </ContentWithTargetPath>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="files\MyDll.dll">
        <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>
        <PackagePath>contentFiles\any\any\;content\any\any</PackagePath>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

So according to the content, no mater I use project reference or package reference to refer A, the static files will always be copied to output folder.

Then I have a project called "B", and it uses project reference to refer A.

The part of the csproj of B is as follow:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\A\A.csproj"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Now I make B be a Nuget package and be referred by C project (Package Reference).

But the static files from A seems not appear in the output folder of C.

Does have any way to deal with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contentFiles node cannot work from a nuget dependency **A** into the main project **C**. And this is quite an issue under my test several times.

It seems that **contentfFiles** node cannot transfer dependencies from nuget to the main project.

**One** of the workaround is to install the **nuget A** into **Project C** additionally.

==========================

**And** the workaround might not be so convenient or you could add these on Project B so that we should not install nuget A additionally:

**1)** add these on Project `B.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
        <None Include="$(TargetDir)\MyDll.dll">
            <Pack>true</Pack>
            <PackagePath>contentFiles\any\any\;content\any\any</PackagePath>
            <PackageCopyToOutput>true</PackageCopyToOutput>         
        </None>     
</ItemGroup>
```

**Then**, repack your **project B**.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried a lot of ways, and this method is worked for me.